# How to fetch value of primary key?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL table where there are three columns: `id`, `name`, and `group`. I want to get the value of `group` from below example:

- Id = 1
- Name = abc
- Group = 1

I need an SQL query from which I can get value `abc` on fetching `group=1`.

Comment: You mention PHP as tag. So I guess you want to get some PHP-code? The answer with pure SQL would simply be:
`select Name from your_table where Group=1;`

Comment: Whats the PHP question?

Comment: Thanks everyone sorry for confusion but i wanted something Select name from tablename where group = myid coloumn value

Actully i am lreaning php and sql where i am creating table in html with heading name and under. I am able to get name but in under coloumn i am getting id i want to show abc here

Comment: What's the primary key

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM table_name_here
WHERE table_name_here.Group = 1
```

Comment: Thanks everyone sorry for confusion but i wanted something Select name from tablename where group = myid coloumn value

Actully i am lreaning php and sql where i am creating table in html with heading name and under. I am able to get name but in under coloumn i am getting id i want to show abc here

Answer (score 0):

You can do if you want to strict filter your request using operator AND/OR.

```
SELECT id, name, group FROM TABLENAME
WHERE id = 1 AND name = "abc" AND group = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone sorry for confusion but i wanted something Select name from tablename where group = myid coloumn value

Actully i am lreaning php and sql where i am creating table in html with heading name and under. I am able to get name but in under coloumn i am getting id i want to show abc here